# Substitute of js variable in php code

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to get an attribute of an element with javascript. So I'm using the following code :

```
 var url = jQuery(this).find('a').attr('url');
```

I get the right value. After that, I want to call a file with ajax by using this `url`. The problem is that I need to use php to call the url but I can't use a js variable inside php code. I want to do something like the following but of course, it doesn't work. Here is the idea of what I want :

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo Mage::getUrl(?>"+url+"<?php);?>",
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
        jQuery(id).html(data);
    }
});
```

Any idea please ?

Comment: First of all you can not change php variable using javascript, remember javacript is a client side while php is server side.

Comment: @muyamwangi I know, that's why I'm looking for a substitute or a solution to my problem

Comment: Where is the php script that you want to call? if they are in the same path just pass the url variable

Answer (score 1):

PHP is server side, javascript is clientside. You can't change your PHP code with javascript. I would suggest to pass the javascript variable as POST data to your AJAX call and redirect it from there.

For example:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "static_url",
    async: false,
    data: {url: url},
    success: function(data) {
        jQuery(id).html(data);
    }
});
```

At the "static_url" page you could do a cURL request to that url by doing

```
<?php 
    $url = Mage::getUrl($_POST['url']); 
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    $output = curl_exec($ch); 
    curl_close($ch);

    echo $output;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the javacsript variable with php. PHP is running server side and javascript is on client side. You need to try something like this.

```
var url = '<?php echo $base_url; ?>/'+url;
```

Comment: I can't because the url is inside a php function :/

Comment: don't you have any php function which return atleast `baseurl` ? What are you using ? any php framework ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you want to achieve

```html
jQuery.ajax({
    url: url,
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
        jQuery(id).html(data);
    }
});
```

Just pass the url variable if this is the path to your php script.

Comment: No, because I need the php function, not only the url

Comment: I can edit my answer if you tell me where the php script is located